# Windows server 2016 network with windows7 windows 10 windows 8 pcs on 2 subnets unable to see each other in network browser?

Tags: windows-server-2016

We have a Windows server 2016 network with windows7 windows 10 windows 8 pcs on 2 subnets these pcs are unable to see each other in network browser?

We have correct parameters on the switches firewall the only place where we are unable to see is in the network browser in the pcs ,we have tried dhcp option 191 for both the vlans and nothing
Packet traces are correct
The ad is correctly setup pdc emulator is correct
Dns dhcp is perfect
This is getting to be critical.
I appreciate all help.
Asb

Answer (score 0):

[Computer Browser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125927(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_browser) service is disabled by default starting with Windows Server 2008 R2. If you can't turn on Network Discovery, follow the resolutions in this support article:

[You cannot turn on Network Discovery in Network and Sharing Center in Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, or Windows Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2722035/you-cannot-turn-on-network-discovery-in-network-and-sharing-center-in)